# How to connect 9 dots with 4 straight lines?

Tags: geometry

The segments can also cut each other.
[image]

I have tried and tried but I can do it with 5 segments only.

Comment: hint: two lines are out the square

Comment: Three horizontal segments and one vertical segment, each passing through three of the points, seem to do the job. I guess it depends on what you mean by "unite them all". What does it mean for a bunch of line segments to "unite" a set of points?

Comment: @bof I believe OP meant a polygonal chain of 4 segments containing all the given dots.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski How did you figure that out? Did you deduce that from the statement of the question? Or are you just assuming that the OP must be referring to a familiar problem which involves the same diagram?

Comment: In my opinion we do the askers no favors by reading their minds and answering the question they meant to ask; rather we should try to urge them to formulate their questions correctly and clearly.

Comment: Your diagram is invisible on a dirty screen like mine xD

Comment: This is a problem I encountered 33 years ago in a non-math setting. It requires thinking out of the box or more precisely "out of square". It took me considerable time, about 3 weeks to solve it.
It should be worded mathematically: Take any square in a PLANE and use only its corner points, the 4 midpoints of its sides and the point of intersection of its diagonals. You have 9 points. Find(show) a CONTINUOUS FIGURE consisting of only 4 "straight" line segments in the plane such that all 9 points mentioned are part of the figure. See the solution figure given above by user167045.
You can also I

Comment: [...] use the 4 corner square points, any 4 other points, one each for each of these 4 sides of square and any one point on one diagonal. [rest of the (converted) comment by Robert Telarket].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this puzzle earlier. So I understand what you mean. This is what you want.[image]

Comment: It cannot be done in three lines as you are assuming the dots to be circles.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Let me edit.