# Connecting $N \times N$ dots with straight lines

Tags: geometry

Many of you have likely seen the [Connect 9 dots with 4 lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166375/how-to-connect-9-dots-with-4-straight-lines) puzzle.  My problem is similar, but more generic.

Given an $N\times N$ square of points, what is the minimum number of lines needed to connect all of the points?

1. Lines must make a path (the endpoints of each of the lines must connect, except for the first and last line).
2. Lines **cannot** go out of square.  This means that the the above puzzle requires 5 lines.
3. The angle of each of the lines must be a multiple of 45.
4. If needed, a point can be connected by multiple lines

Right now, my best method is to create a spiral of lines, which uses $2N-1$ lines.  However, I can't prove that this is the minimum number of lines needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a grid of size $N \times N$ where $N \geq 5$,
it is necessary and sufficient to use $2N - 2$ lines.
The proof is [found here, in an answer to an earlier question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23193/not-lifting-your-pen-on-the-n-times-n-grid)

Although that question and its answers do not explicitly address whether the
lines go outside the grid, and in fact exploit a tracing of an inner
$3\times 3$ grid in which the lines *do* go outside the grid,
the lines go only one step outside the inner $3\times 3$ grid
and remain within the $N \times N$ grid.

For $N < 5$ I believe it is true that $2N - 1$ lines are required
to trace the grid without "going outside" it.

Comment: Wow, despite my searching, I didn't realize my problem has been covered so many times.  I'm pretty sure you are correct on both.